# Gem issues while upgrading to rails 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gem-bundler, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having gem issues when I tried to upgrade to rails 5.1.1, I get the the output below when I run bundle update rails from 4.2: Any ideas what the issue might be?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
railties (~> 5.0)

devise was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
  railties (< 5.2, >= 4.1.0)

quiet_assets (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
  railties (< 5.0, >= 3.1)

rails (~> 5.1.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
  railties (= 5.1.1)

responders (~> 2.1) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
  railties (< 5.3, >= 4.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem may lie with `railties (~> 5.0)` , if you look a little further down then it states that Rails 5.1.1 needs Railties 5.1.1. `rails (~> 5.1.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
  railties (= 5.1.1)`. On a side note, have you upgraded before? It may be worth upgrading from 4.2 to 5.0 and then 5.1 to make sure you catch any errors from deprecated methods. See this -> [Rails Upgrade Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Edit to add:
Looks as though the quiet_assets gem is deprecated. If you need quiet_assets gem then check out this article on silencing asset-logging (explains it better than I can)! [Quiet Assets in Rails 5](https://rossta.net/blog/quiet-assets-in-rails-5.html)